# Variable addresses are not aligned when they are not printed

Tags: c, pointers

I was just wondering about memory address alignment in C. I made this program to see the output addresses. I execute the program with one of the printf lines enable for the test.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
        int number1=1;
        int number2=2;
        int number3=3;
        int number4=4;
        int number5=5;
        printf("number1: %p number5: %p number3: %p number2: %p number4: %p \n",&number1,&number5,&number3,&number2,&number4);
        //printf("number1: %p number5: %p number3: %p  \n",&number1,&number5,&number3);    
}
```

**Result of using the first printf by itself**

> number1: 0x7ffeb26e8abc
>   number5: 0x7ffeb26e8aac
>   number3: 0x7ffeb26e8ab4
>   number2: 0x7ffeb26e8ab8
>   number4: 0x7ffeb26e8ab0

As you can see the last byte in the address is decrementing from the first variable to the last variable. It goes from "bc" to "b8" to "b4" to "b0" to "ac".

**Result of using the second printf by itself.**

> number1: 0x7ffee620d684
>   number5: 0x7ffee620d67c
>   number3: 0x7ffee620d680

You can see that it decrements the address locations starting with the first declared variable number1. it goes from "84 to "80" to "7c".

Based on the first printf test i thought the second test would show unaligned addresses in the print. I expected the addresses to be aligned on the order they were declared.

Expected result for test 2.

- number1 address ends with 84
- number2 address ends with 80
- number3 address ends with 7c
- number4 address ends with 78
- number5 address ends with 74

It does not look like variable number2 and number4 are in the alignment of addresses based on the declaration from the printed statement in test 2..

Questions

1. How come only the printed variable addresses are aligned? Has the compiler said these variables would execute better based on their use if the addresses were aligned.
2. Why are the addresses decremented? I thought they would be incremented as they are being put on the stack? Starting with the first variable address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stacks *often* grow downward, and these variables are on the stack.
2. (a) Your compiler is, of course, free to organize those variables in *any* way it likes. There is no requirement that their addresses be anywhere near each other.  (b) In this case, it's likely that the compiler simply optimized the other variables out of existence, since their values were never used.

Comment: Also, building debug (non-optimzied) vs. retail (optimized) will have dramatic effects on the variable address layout.  If the compiler is using any settings to detect bad program behavior (including security issues), it is likely injecting hidden values in between variables such that it can detect that the stack isn't getting corrupted.